# iOS 8 day view calendar event cell resize on long press

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios8, calendar, xcode6

Does anyone know of any sample code or controls that mimic the iOS 8 calendar app when you click into the current day (day view), press and hold a time slot to create a new calendar event? Also, when you press and hold, you should have the ability to resize the start and end time of the events when you drag your finger along the top or bottom of the cell. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Detecting long press is easy, but resizing the cell to the nearest 15 min (1/4 height) when long pressing on an existing calendar event is what I am looking for.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/erichoracek/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout

Comment: did you found a solution for this?